How to get data back from streamlit component backend to the frontend?
I'm trying to create a streamlit custom component using component template . In the documentation it's stated that "Arguments that are passed to the plugin in Python are accessible via this.props.args" and that the frontend can send data through "Streamlit.setComponentValue". But I wonder if after instantiating the component, getting arguments and sending data, if the backend does some processing on this data, how can we send it to the frontend again ?
I have this function in my init.py file :
def signedUrl_generator(storage_client, credentials, bucket_name, key=None):
files_data = _component_func(key=key, default=[])
signed_urls = generate_put_signed_urls(files_data, storage_client, credentials, bucket_name)

return signed_urls

And I need to send the signed_urls back to the frontend so that it can use them to upload some documents.
